# C# regular expression for American phone numbers without hyphens or parentheses?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for something that will validate the following:

- 13175551234
- 3175551234

but NOT validate:

- 1 (317) 531 1234
- 1-317-555-1234

Basically it should validate 10 or 11 digit phone numbers that can optionally begin with 1 and don't contain spaces, hyphens or parentheses. The area code should not be optional either.

How can I do this?

Comment: What language are you using? Regular expression syntax differs depending on the language.

Comment: Major poopoo on my part. Im using C# 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually pretty straightforward: `^1?\d{10}$`

Comment: This one allows phone numbers (without 1 for long distance) that start with 1. For instance, 155-555-5555 is not a valid US phone number, but your regex will accept it as such. (Not downvoting, as it's a good effort.)

Comment: Let's hope he is using javascript... Otherwhise ৩৩৩৩৩৩৩৩৩৩ will be a valid number! (\d catches non-euro-american digits, that is the Bengali Digit Three U+09E9 :-) ) (Javascript considers digits only 0-9)

Comment: Personal research on this suggests that RegexOptions.ECMAScript seems to remedy this and enable Jscript compliance. Kudos for the regular expression gentlemen. No Bengali nationals will be using my SMS notifications service for any would be nefarious plots or terrorist operations.

Answer (score 1):

For something simple you could try this:

```
"^1?[0-9]{10}$"
```

Or slightly better:

```
"^1?[2-9][0-9]{9}$"
```

But this still matches incorrectly for some situations. For a better approach, see this answer:

- [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation/123666#123666)

Depending on the programming language you are using may want to use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. But please be aware that in C# `\d` can match *any* digits as defined by the Unicode standard. So it can include Chinese numerals and other numeric characters that are illegal characters in a phone number. However `[0-9]` works everywhere, even in Unicode aware languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^1?[^0-1][0-9]{9}$
```

It matches

```
13155551212
3155551212
```

It doesn't match

```
03155551212
10315551212
1055551212
11555551212
```

Comment: That also matches 1৩155551212.

Comment: @Mark Don't steal my preciousss Bengali Digit Three! Take another Bengali Digit!! :-) :-)

Comment: @xanatos: Actually I was going to write `1W155551212` because that also matches, but I thought your Bengali digit three was much cooler. :)

Comment: @Mark A present for you: ৪ (no, it isn't an eight... It's a PRECIOUS BENGALI DIGIT FOUR!!!) :-)

Comment: @xanatos: That's neat! Great input to trick people into wasting several hours debugging why their regular expressions aren't working. :)